# Translation Golf XLVII — I'm a bᵃᵃᵃᵃᵃᵃᵈ ᵍᵘᵘᵘʸʸʸʸʸʸ

Tags: traducción, translation-golf, inglés

I mean -- I don't see what she sees
But maybe it's 'cause [this Charlie's answer won](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30974).

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game! If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

This week's proposed text is taken from Billie Eilish's last hit song: [***bad guy***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyDfgMOUjCI).
Here's the first verse:

> White shirt now red, my bloody nose
>   Sleeping, you're on your tippy toes
>   Creeping around like no one knows
>   Think you're so criminal
>   Bruises, on both my knees for you
>   Don't say thank you or please. I do
>   What I want when I'm wanting to
>   My soul? So cynical
>
> <sub>(195 characters)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

My own, non-golfed, rather sloppy and probably debatable translation:

> Camisa blanca, ahora roja, mi nariz sangrante
>  Durmiendo, estás de puntillas
>  Arrastrándote por ahí como si nadie se diese cuenta
>  Piensas que eres tan criminal
>  Arañazos en mis dos rodillas por ti
>  No digas gracias o por favor. Yo hago
>  Lo que quiero cuando me apetece
>  ¿Mi alma? Tan cínica
>  
>  <sub>(229 characters)</sub>

**Concepts that *must* appear in the translation**: physical descriptions (colors, movements, body parts, wounds etc.) should probably be kept, as well as the general meaning of the verse. Just be creative and I'll warn you if you cross any lines.

---

General rules for this game are as follows:

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- **Rhyme bonus**: if you are up for a challenge, keep the number and rhyme of lines to get a **10% discount bonus** in your total char count!

  - The rhyming pattern is AAABCCCB. To get the full bonus you must manage to get a *consonante* rhyme for those lines in Spanish; however, an *asonante* rhyme will still get you a good 5%. [Info about rhyme types in Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rima).
  - Please note that you don't need to keep the metric too: if you weren't allowed to make the lines shorter, there wouldn't be much golfing left to do ;-)

Also, remember that not every character counts for the total: only letters and numbers do. You can paste your translation in the letter counter linked below to obtain your char count.

- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contestants? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Comment: ¡¡¡¡¡Trraaaaaaaannnnnnnsslaaaaaaaaatiiiiiooooooooooonnnnnn ggoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooolllllfffffffffff!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### <strike>132 130 125,4</strike> 119,7 puntos (126 * 0,95)

> [Naso](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QHElAR1) sangra: blusa [ex](https://dle.rae.es/?id=HA2tbn5)-alba.
>   Duermo, [de punta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UfIf0Lu) pasas,
>   algo [cueces](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9ZB8fkz), [vaya](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bPmU3j2).
>   [Reo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=VzNDjEg) te ves.
>   [Morados](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Plr9pOR) en mis rodillas, por ti.
>   ¿Gracias, ruegos? No a mí.
>   Mi alma [ruin](https://dle.rae.es/?id=WoYnxu0)
>   hace su [placer](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TI9Rqvd).

<strike>De momento sin rima.</strike> Conseguida una rima asonante con la estructura AAABCCCB requerida.

Explicaciones:

- Al usar *ex-* con el significado de "que fue y ha dejado de serlo", se entiende que la camisa ya no es alba (blanca). Preceder la frase con la referencia a la sangre hace entender que ahora es roja. Ha quedado un poco con estilo haiku.
- Se usa *cocer* en el sentido de "preparar o tramar algo con sigilo".
- Se usa *vaya* para indicar decepción o disgusto, lo que implica que quien lo dice es conocedor de lo que pasa y ha emitido un juicio de valor.
- Se usa *placer* como sinónimo de "voluntad" (acepción 3).

Agradecimientos:

- -2 caracteres gracias a RubioRic.

Comentarios sobre versiones anteriores:

- Una *mosqueta* es una hemorragia nasal, palabra típica [gaditana](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provincia_de_C%C3%A1diz). No está en el DLE pero doy fe de su uso por estas tierras, además de que el *Fichero general* la recoge en la [ficha 83 de la entrada *mosqueta*](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_M/LETRA_M_PDF/MOSQUETA/00000926.pdf) (PDF), aludiendo al *Vocabulario andaluz* de Alcalá Vencelada. De hecho antiguamente una *mosqueta* era un golpe en la nariz que provocaba hemorragia, pero hoy día se usa solo para cuando te sangra la nariz por el motivo que sea. Se elimina la palabra por no aparecer en el DLE y por haber encontrado una forma más corta de expresarlo.

Comment: que prisas, yo estaba esperando que pusieran la pregunta wiki

Comment: @blonfu por eso aún no he votado, pero eso no quita para que responda...

Comment: era la escusa, en realidad es que no me ha dado ni tiempo

Comment: ¿Se pueden hacer sugerencias de mejora? Cambiar "moretones" por "morados" reduce el conteo.